# Forge Get/Share Link

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm running our Forge Viewer within our internal intranet site.  Is there any way to share a model with an outside client via the free [A360 viewer](https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/#) or similar remote viewer? That site has the ability to share models via "Get Link" in the upper right.  If not, what's the proper approach to sharing work stored on Forge with outside clients/vendors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question, the link you point out is the only official tool that we have to share a model with a customer - as far as I know. If your viewer application is running on an internal intranet site how would you go about sharing anything to the outside world...?

Comment: Correct.  Let's assume my company designs some parts and chooses to catalog them in Forge via our internal website or AutoCAD/Revit/Inventor add-ins that talk to Forge directly.  How would I share those documents with outside manufacturers via Forge?  Is that even possible using Forge services?

Comment: Do you want to share the CAD files themselves? Or share the design through the viewer? In the first case you could use the data management OSS API which is a simple cloud file storage API, in the second case you translate the cad files so they can be loaded in the viewer. In both cases you would need to create a web application where you have to handle yourself things like user accounts, login, security ...

Comment: ... and your customers can log to your web app and load designs in the viewer or download the files stored on OSS - but only by going through your app, because your server is the one issuing valid oauth tokens so files can be accessed or loaded in the viewer only from where you decide to ... Hope that helps, let me know if some points need to be clarified.

Comment: Adding to that, you can also implement features in your web app that would allow you to generate permanent or temporary share links (private - which require login to your webapp or public), so you can send a link to a specific design to a customer. This kind of feature could be handled by your own server/database logic that map a url to a specific design URN

Comment: That all makes sense.  It would depend on the manufacturer what they would require file-wise but I'm hoping in the future most files can just get retrieved via Forge using some of the ideas you described.

Comment: Forge is a set of building blocks to create custom web applications that can leverage the Autodesk technologies. If your needs are about file-sharing there are many cloud-based solutions at any price level, starting from free, that you can use right now. Note that with Autodesk A360 you can already create hubs -containing projects, sub folders and files... - that can be shared with customers.